Uniswap/Sushiswap: How to grab/calculate APY?
I am trying to understand if it is possible to use oracles or interfaces that can provide the APY of a specific protocol ERC-20. Essentially, I would like to write a smart contract that allows depositing funds into a protocol while knowing the current calculated APY.
I am not sure, apologies as I am new to this field, if this value is only statistical (ie, calculated from past data) or if it is known in real-time while staking.
If it is calculated, are there any resources you could recommend to implement this functionality? Thank you.
